# Stable under finite intersection

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $X$ a set, $\mathcal{P}(X)$ its power set and $\mathcal{T} \subset \mathcal{P}(X)$.

Is it true that $\mathcal{T}$ stable under finite intersection (i.e. $\forall A, B \in \mathcal{T}, A \cap B \in \mathcal{T}$) implies $X \in \mathcal{T}$ ? Since $|\emptyset| = 0$ and $\cap_{i \in \emptyset}A_{i} = X$ ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope. Consider $\mathcal T=\emptyset,$ which is stable under finite intersection, vacuously.

As another counterexample, consider $X=\{x,y,z\}$ to be your favorite $3$-element set, and then consider $$\mathcal T=\bigl\{\{x,z\},\{y,z\},\{z\}\bigr\}.$$

---

By contrast, consider the following condition for $\mathcal T$:

$$\forall\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal T,|\mathcal S|<\aleph_0\implies\bigl\{x\in X:\forall S\in\mathcal S,x\in S\bigr\}\in\mathcal T.$$

This would be another way we could express "stable under finite intersection," and would imply that $X\in\mathcal T$ (so long as $\mathcal T\neq\emptyset$), for exactly the reason you claim.

The issue is that your condition (as stated) can be proved equivalent to the following: $$\forall\mathcal S\subseteq\mathcal T,\color{red}{0<}|\mathcal S|<\aleph_0\implies\bigl\{x\in X:\forall S\in\mathcal S,x\in S\bigr\}\in\mathcal T.$$

Comment: Ok, I see it depend on how one intepret "stable under finite intersection".